# SCIMetalRenderSurface will stay empty

Tags: swift, metal, scichart

I’m trying to use the metal support in a little test project.
I have following lines to enable metal:

```
if SCIChartSurface.isMetalSupported {
      sciChartSurface.renderSurface = SCIMetalRenderSurface(frame: sciChartSurface.bounds)
 } else {
       sciChartSurface.renderSurface = SCIOpenGLRenderSurface(frame: sciChartSurface.bounds)
 }
```

the surface keeps empty until I remove the

```
sciChartSurface.renderSurface = SCIMetalRenderSurface(frame: sciChartSurface.bounds)
```

line – or in other words I use OpenGL.
Then the chart will render properly. I am using an iPhoneX (not simulator).

Thank you for your support!

Here is the complete Wall of Code

```
import UIKit
import SciChart
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - UIElements
    private var sciChartSurface: SCIChartSurface!

    // MARK: - Vars
    private var series: SCIXyDataSeries?

    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupSurface()
        setupData()
        renderData()
    }

       // MARK: - Chart
     private func setupSurface() {
        // Create a SCIChartSurface. This is a UIView so can be added directly to the UI
        sciChartSurface = SCIChartSurface.init(frame: view.bounds)
        sciChartSurface.debugWhySciChartDoesntRender = true
        view.addSubview(sciChartSurface)

        // Detect metal with this static property
        if SCIChartSurface.isMetalSupported {
            sciChartSurface.renderSurface = SCIMetalRenderSurface(frame: sciChartSurface.bounds)
        } else {
            sciChartSurface.renderSurface = SCIOpenGLRenderSurface(frame: sciChartSurface.bounds)
        }
        sciChartSurface.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }

        sciChartSurface.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        sciChartSurface.backgroundColor = .gray
        // Create an XAxis and YAxis. This step is mandatory before creating series
        let xAxis = SCICategoryNumericAxis()
        setup(axis: xAxis)
        sciChartSurface.xAxes.add(xAxis)
        let yAxis = SCINumericAxis()
        setup(axis: yAxis)
        sciChartSurface.yAxes.add(yAxis)
    }

    private func setup(axis: SCIAxisBase) {
        let axisStyle = SCIAxisStyle()

        let majorPen = SCISolidPenStyle(colorCode: 0xFF393532, withThickness: 0.5)
        let minorPen = SCISolidPenStyle(colorCode: 0xFF262423, withThickness: 0.5)

        let textFormat = SCITextFormattingStyle()
        textFormat.fontSize = 16

        axisStyle.majorTickBrush = majorPen
        axisStyle.majorGridLineBrush = majorPen
        axisStyle.gridBandBrush = SCISolidBrushStyle(colorCode: 0xE1232120)
        axisStyle.minorTickBrush = minorPen
        axisStyle.minorGridLineBrush = minorPen
        axisStyle.labelStyle = textFormat
        axisStyle.drawMinorGridLines = true
        axisStyle.drawMajorBands = true
        axis.style = axisStyle
    }

    private func setupData() {
        series = SCIXyDataSeries(xType: .int16, yType: .int16)
        TestData.testData.forEach { (testData) in
            let xGeneric = SCIGenericType(type: .int16, .init(int32Data: testData.x))
            let yGeneric = SCIGenericType(type: .int16, .init(int32Data: testData.y))
            series?.appendX(xGeneric, y: yGeneric)
        }
    }

    private func renderData() {
        let renderSeries = SCIFastColumnRenderableSeries()
        renderSeries.dataSeries = series
        sciChartSurface.renderableSeries.add(renderSeries)
    }
}



struct TestData {
    var x: Int32
    var y: Int32

    static let testData = [TestData(x: 2017, y: 5),
                           TestData(x: 2018, y: 8),
                           TestData(x: 2019, y: 2),
                           TestData(x: 2020, y: 9)]
}
```

Comment: Hey Hans, a very similar question was asked over here and the scichart developers asked for code to reproduce, as they couldn’t reproduce it. Can you send them some code to repro? They will be very happy to help https://www.scichart.com/questions/ios/scimetalrendersurface-will-stay-empty